# Go to next character under cursor in Vim

Tags: vim, editor

As stated in the header, I would like to go to the next occurrence of the character currently under the cursor in Vim. I know about `f <character>`, etc., but I specifically want "this" character. How do I do this?

Comment: If your cursor is on character `s`, then `fs;` will take you to its next occurrence. Repeated hits to `;` will keep taking you to the further occurrences of `s`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not exist natively.

If you want, you can create a new mapping (bound to  `<leader>a` for example). Add the following to your .vimrc and restart:

```
nnoremap <leader>a vy/<C-R>"<CR>


" vy : copy the character under the cursor
" / : open search
" <C-R>" : paste the character
" <CR> : launch the search
```

Then each following search will be available via the <kbd>n</kbd> key as usual.

(Leader is by defaut the <kbd>\</kbd> key but can be remapped with the command :`set mapleader =` )

This is not part of the question, but I should add that for easy navigation, it is a good idea to have look at [easymotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion) plugin and know that it exists.

Comment: I would rather use a mapping like this: `:nnoremap <silent> <leader>a vy/<C-R>='\V'.escape(getreg('"'),'\\/')<CR><CR>` That will escape special chars correctly.

Comment: @gustafbstrom: Christian's addition is probably better in the end, but if are only limiting yourself, to ascii char it should be good enough.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ascii, but rather if you are on a dot, you usually rather want to jump to the next dot rather than any other character (since the dot has a special meaning in a regex)

Comment: Two useful additions: 1. To eliminate the search highlight append `:noh<CR>` to the command. 2. If you want to search backwards you can add nnoremap `<leader>A vy?<C-R>"<CR>:noh<CR>`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a built-in equivalent to `*` for the character under the cursor but the mappings below should cover your requirements:

```
nnoremap <silent> <key> "zyl:normal! f^Rz^M
nnoremap <silent> <key> "zyl:normal! F^Rz^M
nnoremap <silent> <key> "zyl:normal! t^Rz^M
nnoremap <silent> <key> "zyl:normal! T^Rz^M
```

`^R` is obtained with `<C-v><C-r>` and `^M` with `<C-v><CR>`.

Comment: Could you clarify what `<C-v><C-r>` does? For me, a single `Ctrl-R` seems to work fine.

Comment: `<C-v><C-r>` is used to insert a literal `^R` in the buffer.

Comment: using keynotation like `<c-r>` should work and makes it more readable.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

`yl:normal! f<Ctrl-R>"<CR>`

Explanation:

`yl`— yank (copy) the character under cursor into the `"` register
`:normal` — execute a Normal mode command that follows
`f<Ctrl-R>"<CR>` — insert the contents of the `"` register and run the `f{char}` command.

Of course, you'll want to create a mapping for the command to make it usable.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a visual mapping on `*` that searches for the next thing selected (like this [one](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/v_star.vim)), you'll just have to type  `v*`

NB: there exist several entries on SO about how to extend |start| to visual mode, and one on vim.wikia.

Answer (score 0):

Use `*` to search forward for the [count]'th occurrence of the word nearest to the cursor. I doubt there is a key for next character, but you can `/x` then `n` to goto the next `x`.